# Шифр Цезаря. Символы строки должны циклически сдвигаться на +1 каждой строки

Tags: python

```
import string

with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as text:
    text_translate = text.read()
    
delta = 1 # смещение
lower = (string.ascii_lowercase[delta:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:delta])
translate = {ord(a): d for (a, d) in zip(string.ascii_letters, (lower + lower.upper()))}
result = str.translate(text_translate, translate)

print(result)
```

У меня не переходит смещение на следующую строку, дано:
text.txt файл, в нем 4 строки с текстом Hello
Результат должен быть вот таким:

```
Ifmmp
Jgnnq
Khoor
Lipps
```

А у меня вот так :(

```
Ifmmp
Ifmmp
Ifmmp
Ifmmp
```

Comment: `H` отображается в `I` на любой строке файла. "Вот так" у вас правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, наверное, тогда нужно в цикле чтения файла сдвиг менять:

```py
import string

with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as text:
    for delta, text_translate in enumerate(text.readlines(), 1):
        lower = (string.ascii_lowercase[delta:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:delta])
        translate = {ord(a): d for (a, d) in zip(string.ascii_letters, (lower + lower.upper()))}
        result = str.translate(text_translate, translate)

        print(result)
```

Comment: вы правы, спасибо.